# how to check whether a button is clicked, inside another button click event in windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

well i am having two buttons on a form and I want to start data transfer with the first button and stop on the press of a second button.

code is:

```
private void stdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopped = false;

    //while (stopped == false)

    if (sender == spdaq)
    {
        stopped = true;
        ///break;
        Process();
    }
    else if (sender == stdaq)
    {
        Process();
    }
}
```

here stdaq is the start button and spdaq is the stop button, the process function is a function which i am implementing and in that with the stopped variable of bool type i am implementing two different functions inside process method, but i want to continually check whether the stop button is pressed or not but here with this code i got no success.

so please help me with how to pass the value true to the stopped variable inside the event click function of start button itself on the press of stop button.

Comment: Is process some long running method or one that you run again every click?

Comment: process is a long running method , you can assume it as a method i am calling it in a while loop and on press of stop button it should just come out of it

Comment: Then you need to make process run on a separate thread and then periodically (at safe times) check if the method needs to be cancelled

Comment: @Sayse, please help by giving some code for the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write a full answer at the minute but [this, How to: Use a Background Worker,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create cancellation token, start asynchronous Task in button start event handler put your method in this Task, pass reference to this cancellation token and use 
it to stop this task in Stop button event handler when you'll need it later.

More information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx

Example of how you can use it:

```
    static CancellationTokenSource cts;
    static Task t;

    private void Method()
    {
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) 
        {
             // your logic here
        }
        t = null;
    }

    private void stdaq_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
       if(t != null) return;
       cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       t = new Task(Method, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);
       t.Start();
    }

    private void spdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       if(t != null) cts.Cancel(); 
    }
```

Comment: You should really work on formatting your code better.

Comment: This would cause `Process` currently to run on the ui thread so you'd never get the opportunity to click `spdaq`

Comment: @Sayse, correct i implemented this and this freezes my form

Comment: That's exactly why i added 2nd option with Async Task... It depends on what is inside your 'while' loop. Some operations do block thread some not. If you need your UI thread to be working all the time you need to start new thread or Task

Comment: @Fabjan, can you please give me some sample, i am unable to understand from the link you had given

Comment: thanks, but how to link it with buttons of start and stop, as i am unable to get where to place the click events for those buttons, also in the commented part where its written i have to write the process functions, am i right?

Comment: Check it again please.

Comment: @Fabjan, thanks for your valuable response, but here by implementing this code there is a problem with the process method, the method is not implemented properly, it is bypassing some commands.

Comment: If you want to pass some parameters inside this Task then you should box it to object (obj) and use other ctor overload:  new Task(Method, obj, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);  Inside your Task you can then unbox it like YourClass t = obj as YourClass and work with this data.

Comment: thanks @Fabjan, i some how manage to solve the problem, and your answer was quite valuable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use two separate Handlers for the start and the stop button. This makes your logic much simpler to follow. Then do soemthing like this:

```
private void stdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start
{
    Process(true);
}

private void spdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Stop
{
    Process(false);
}
```

Or even better: Create two seperate Methods `StartProcess()` and `StopProcess()`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i can't modify the function process as it is provided by some one for a sensor, and with that method process i am getting a data continuously, so with this event type i want to call process in a while loop or so, but as soon as the stop button is pressed i want it to exit the loop